# Is this notation feature a kind of "variable shadowing"?

Tags: notation

I'm a programmer, hence the term "shadowing" in the title.

In C++ programming, you can do the following:

```
void foo() {
    int i = 5;
    {
        int i = 6;
    }
}
```

The two `i`s here are separate variables. The `i` in the inner scope is said to "shadow" the other `i`.

I'm reading [this paper](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Erkm38/pdfs/mantiuk06pfcphdri.pdf), equation 21:

> [image]
>
> [image]

Here's how I read the equation:

"for each `i` in [0, N], a triple-nested sum (depending on i) should equal 0"

The problem is that the "triple-nested sum" introduces another variable that is also called `i`. Is this notation equivalent to the shadowing in the C++ snippet above?

Comment: Please type the equation in your question.

Answer (score 3):

That looks terrible and should never have happened. When you see the terms $\Phi_i$, $p_{i, j}^k$, $x_i$ and $\hat G_{i, j}^k$, there is no way of knowing which of those $i$'s is a summation index, and which of them correspond to the $\partial x_i$ from the left-hand side of the equality.

So the person who wrote it may have known very well how the expression worked, and think it obvious which $i$'s are summation variables and which aren't, or the ambiguity may not have crossed their mind at all. Either way, I would consider it illegible as it stands, but maybe I would consider it "barely legible" if I had actually read all of the paper and knew what the equation was about.

To answer your actual question, yes, there is definitely something very shadowing-like going on here. The big problem is that they then probably use $i$ to refer to both the local and the global variable at different points in the same expression (in the same "scope", to use a programming term), with no objective way of telling which is which.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it.

In $\partial x_i$, the $x_i$ refers to one of the arguments of `f` (in equation 7). Equation 7 "invisibly" uses $x_i$, as $G_{i, j}^k$ is defined in terms of $x_i$. And indeed the other usages of `i` are shadowing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here we have some kind of *variable shadowing*. First of all note there is *no ambiguity* regarding the expression (21), but the *readability* might be affected by the multiple use of the variable $i$.

> We have the following situation
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}&=\sum_{k=1}^K\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j\in\Phi_i}2p_{i,j}^k\left(x_i^k-x_j^k-\hat{G}_{i,j}^k\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^K\left(\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j\in\Phi_i}2p_{i,j}^k\left(x_i^k-x_j^k-\hat{G}_{i,j}^k\right)\right)\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^K\sum_{\color{blue}{l}=1}^N\sum_{j\in\Phi_\color{blue}{l}}2p_{\color{blue}{l},j}^k\left(x_\color{blue}{l}^k-x_j^k-\hat{G}_{\color{blue}{l},j}^k\right)\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}

- The  subscript variable $i$ at the left-hand side of (1) is a *[free  variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables)*.
- The index variable $i$ at the right hand side is a *bound variable* according to the scope of the $\sum$-symbol. The scope of the bound variable is indicated by the open brackets in (2).
- We can clarify the situation for instance by using a different bound variable $l$ instead of $i$ as shown in (3).

*Note:* The scope of the sigma operator $\sum$ is solely defined via *[arithmetic precedence rules](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mc-ty-rules-2009-1.pdf)*. The scope is given by the expression that follows immediately the $\sum$ and is valid respecting the arithmetic precedence rules up to an operator with precedence level equal to '$+$' or up to the end if no such operator follows.